# C++ vs native implementation of iOS/android

Tags: android, c++, ios

I'm developing an app for iOS and android that identifies songs.  We have a matching engine in c++ that works well, but my question is about the rest of the app.  We have a user interface design that allows the user to record, match and save, as well as share, edit, and see their recordings.
I'm not a coder - just a designer- and I'm getting conflicting advice about how to implement.  One person wants to do the majority of the interface in c++ with just a thin native GUI skin, while the other says we should write in native IOS (swift) and Android and only have the engine in c++.  The argument for c++ is it will be a single code base to maintain - it would include doing the sharing, storing history, displaying sonograms, etc.  The argument against is that in fact it will not be easier to maintain, and will also create a lot of problems making calls, for example, between the interface and the sharing module.
Hope this is clear - it's a very hard thing for me to assess as ignorant as I am!  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the way to go is to write the GUI the way it was meant to be. Native iOS/Android will yield a much better user experience and will allow you to use the platform latest and greatest way of implementing a UI.

Also, I am assuming that the engine will probably not be developped by the same people that develop the GUI itself, so the argument that it would be simpler to have a single code base doesn't really make sense.

Another solution could be to use Xamarin, so that you can consolidate iOS and Android development, while still having a common C++ engine.

Edit: Typo

Comment: Thanks so much on that - this is the way I've been leaning, but the person who coded the engine seems very adamant that doing as much in possible in C++ would save us maintenance time in the future.  Someone else told me that this is a well-known "myth" in the programming community, and that in practice it is actually harder.  Appreciate your feedback!